# About Clojure's Laziness

Tags: clojure

I feel curious about clojure's *lazy sequence*. In REPL, I defined a variable *foo*:

```
user> (def foo (map println [1 2 3]))
#'user/foo
```

At the **first** time evaluating *foo*, it seems to work:

```
user> foo
1
2
3
(nil nil nil)
```

But after the **first** time, why it becomes lazy?

```
user> foo
(nil nil nil)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`println` is not a **pure** function, what you're seeing in the first time you evaluate `foo` is the *side effect* of `println`. When you evaluate `foo` for the second time `println` is not called again, because the result of `(map println [1 2 3])` is **cached**.

And you can see that `map` is lazy because when you defined `foo` nothing gets printed in the console. Only when evaluating `foo` something is printed.

Please see [Laziness in Clojure](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/language/laziness.html).

If you use a **pure** function like `inc`:

```
(def foo (map inc [1 2 3]))

> foo
(2 3 4)

> foo
(2 3 4)
```

The result is always the same without any *side effects*. [`map`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/map), [`filter`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/filter), [etc](http://clojure.org/sequences) in Clojure are designed to be used with **pure** functions but the language doesn't forbid you from using them with functions with *side effects*. In Haskell, for example you can't even write an equivalent expression, the code won't compile.

Comment: So, the result of (map println [1 2 3]) is cached after the first run; the cached result is not the sequence itself, but is a seqal object. Is my understanding right?

Comment: The result is a `seqable` that contains the result of applying `println` to every element of the sequence `[1 2 3]`. But `println` returns `nil` so the `seqable` returned by `map` is `(nil nil nil)`.

Answer (score 2):

Collections hold values. The value returned by `println` is `nil`. The side-effect of `println` is to make something show up on your screen.

The values created by mapping `println` are stored in your var. This is a lazy-seq of `nil` values, which were returned by `println`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on your question.
`println` is only having a side effect on the `*out*` stream which is bound by default to the standard output.

You can have both the printing and some value returned from the function you `map`, e.g.

```
user> (defn print-and-inc [n]
        (do
          (println "called with n= " n)
          (inc n)))
#'user/print-and-inc
```

`do` will execute each expression in sequence and return the result of the last, `(inc n)` in this case.
If you define now `foo` as a mapping of `print-and-inc` over a `vector` of `int`

```
user> (def foo (map print-and-inc [1 2 3 4 5]))
#'user/foo
user> 
user> foo
called with n=  1
called with n=  2
called with n=  3
called with n=  4
called with n=  5
(2 3 4 5 6)
user> 
user> foo
(2 3 4 5 6)
```

And you see the lazyness of `map`, since the printing occurs only the first time `foo` is called.  But now `foo` holds the results which are the incremented values of the initial collection.

Note : this can be used to log/trace infos into your code, but there is a standard library [tools.logging](https://github.com/clojure/tools.logging)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has been pointed out by others, note that experimenting with laziness within the repl is a little problematic. Lazy sequences don't actually have values until they are realised by some action that uses the value. The repl has an implicit doall to do this when printing results. This means the sequence is often realised when your using it in the repl, but may not be when using it in your real code.  When you run your code, you get an unexpected result because the sequence has not been realised at a point where you expected it to be because the repl implicit doall has not been called. As an example of how this can cause moments of confusion, have a look at http://nicksellen.co.uk/2013/10/26/clojure-lazy-repl.html

Comment: This post is pretty important for new clojure developers. Thank you very much!